# Print the stack trace of external library

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've a very simple python application which calls into another library. I would like to print the calling path (stack trace) for that call. How can I do that in python?

For:

```
import datetime
x = datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-1-1', "%Y-%m-%d")
```

I would like to see the what strptime does inside.

Thanks,
Eden

Comment: Are you using an IDE, for example using PyCharm it's straightforward to Ctrl + Click a function and skip to the source code where you can find the implementation

Comment: You can use the [`pdb`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) module and call [`pdb.set_trace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdb.set_trace) before the line you want to _trace_, then you can use `pdb` facilities to inspect every aspect of what's going on.

Comment: @SvenHarris - I don't use an IDE.